# TFS 2012 scrum bug with parent as backlog item

Tags: tfs, scrum, bug-tracking

Maybe I am not understanding the scrum development model correctly, but I am confused why TFS places bugs on a different row than my backlog item even if the backlog item is set as its parent.

I thought that we would make a bug report, and it be placed in the TO DO column. Then as you commit code to that bug, you associate the commits with that particular task ID for the bug. Then once it is done it is moved to DONE. Is that not how scrum works? What is the typical process for fixing a reported bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the view of the task board. In the most recent Scrum process template (Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.x), the Bug is in the Requirements category. Doing so, the Bug is treated like a Product Backlog Item (it can be stacked ranked, broken down into workable tasks, and fed through the process like any other PBI). If you are on TFS 2012 Update 1, or TFService, you should have a Kanban board tab on the product backlog page which is where you would move your bugs through the states (New/Approved/Committed/Done). In the task board (screenshot above), the Bugs and Product Backlog Items will be shown as rows (where you have *Task Here* and *Bug Here*) and the the tasks will exist in the To do, In progress, and Done columns.

When you work against a bug, you work specifically against the tasks, and associate/resolve those tasks as you check in code. Once your 'Definition of Done' has been met, you can then move the Bug work item (on the Kanban board, or manually via the state field) to Done.

Answer (score 1):

We are developing agile tools for TFS since 2008 at Urban Turtle. In the 2012 version we did exactly what you are looking for. Green line represent User Story (PBI) and red box represent bugs.

You can try our [Product online](http://urbanturtle.com) if you want.

This is a print screen of the feature you requested. If you need more info just contact me. ddanis@urbanturtle.com

[image]